# Compare int and varchar column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, compare

I have two columns in my table, one contains numbers, and the other should have some strings generated from these numbers like:

```
ID     Serial
1      SN00001
2      SN00002
127    SN00127
```

However I can't be sure if every serial number is correct. So I want to search for any possible mistakes with something like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID <> Serial
```

Of course I can't just write `ID <> Serial`, I guess I should use some substring selecting, type casting and so on but it's all new to me and I could use some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
SELECT * from MyTable WHERE ID <> RIGHT(Serial, LEN(ID))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
from   MyTable 
WHERE  ID <> CAST(REPLACE(Serial, 'SN','') AS INT)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/831a7/2)